# Find a closed form for the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prednisone is often prescribed for acute asthma attacks. For 5 mg tablets, typical instructions are: “Take 8 tablets the first day, 7 the second, and decrease by one tablet each day until all tablets are gone.” Prednisone decays exponentially in the body, and 24 hours after taking k mg, there are kx mg in the body.

(a) Write formulas involving x for the amount of prednisone in the body

...........(i) 24 hours after taking the first dose (of 8 tablets), right before taking the second dose (of 7 tablets).

...........(ii) Immediately after taking the second dose (of 7 tablets).

...........(iii) Immediately after taking the third dose (of 6 tablets).

...........(iv) Immediately after taking the eighth dose (of 1 tablet).

...........(v) 24 hours after taking the eighth dose.

...........(vi) n days after taking the eighth dose.

(b) Find a closed form for the sum T = 8x^7 + 7x^6 + 6x^5 + ••• + 2x + 1, which is the number of prednisone tablets in the body immediately after taking the eighth dose.

(c) If a patient takes all the prednisone tablets as prescribed, how many days after taking the eighth dose is there less than 3% of a prednisone tablet in the patient's body? The half-life of prednisone is about 24 hours.

(d) A patient is prescribed n tablets of prednisone the first day, n - 1 the second, and one tablet fewer each day until all tablets are gone. Write a formula that represents Tn, the number of prednisone tablets in the body immediately after taking all tablets. Find a closed form sum for Tn.